# jquery-ui: Formatting lost after download

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently trying to use jquery-ui v1.12.1; however, much of the formatting for practically all the widgets on the [demo on the website](https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) is lost when I open the `index.html` file in the download. The file uses jquery v1.12.4; I have also unsuccessfully tried to use jquery v3.3.1 for the page's script. `jquery-ui.css`, `external/jquery/jquery.js`, and `jquery-ui.js` are all included in the page source.

Is there something, such as a .css file, that I am missing? What can I do to retrieve the formatting as seen on the site's demo? Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Screenshot (jquery-ui website on left, index.html file from download on right)]

Comment: How are you getting the download? You have to download one of the zips with the CSS. Also, how are you serving the index.html page? Are you just opening it directly from the filesystem? You may need to run a web server.

Comment: Check the browser network tab to ensure the .css files are loading correctly (doesn't look like they are)

Comment: Basically, you have not included the proper CSS. Either it is not linked properly or is not in the proper locations. Please make sure you update your post with the content of you `<head>` section so we can assist better.

Comment: Thank you, i discovered that there was a .css file that I forgot to download.